# Python - retrieving whether article has author

Tags: python

I am trying to write a Python script that retrieves whether an article has an author or not.

I wrote the following:

```
s = "https://www.nytimes.com/2017/08/18/us/politics/steve-bannon-trump-white-house.html?hp&action=click&pgtype=Homepage&clickSource=story-heading&module=a-lede-package-region&region=top-news&WT.nav=top-news"

def checkForAuthor():
    r = requests.get(s)
    return "By" in r.text

print(checkForAuthor())
```

The issue is that function `checkForAuthor`returns `true` even when there's no author because it searches the whole HTML content for the word.
Is there a better logic for finding an author without searching the whole document? Such as searching within a header so I don't even have to search the article content. I do need to make this general so that any website I go search within it will give me the result. Not sure there's anything out there like that.

Comment: you should parse the HTML with some appropriate library and inspect only the tags you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

To parse the html and look for the data you want, you should use the `BeautifulSoup` library.

In the html of your URL, there is a `meta` tag with the author:

```
<meta content="By MAGGIE HABERMAN, MICHAEL D. SHEAR and GLENN THRUSH" name="byl"/>
```

So, to check if there is an author, you need to find it by its name (`byl`):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = "https://www.nytimes.com/2017/08/18/us/politics/steve-bannon-trump-white-house.html?hp&action=click&pgtype=Homepage&clickSource=story-heading&module=a-lede-package-region&region=top-news&WT.nav=top-news"

def checkForAuthor():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(s).content, 'html.parser')
    meta = soup.find('meta', {'name': 'byl'})
    return meta is not None
```

In fact, you can also get the author name with `meta["content"]`

Answer (score 0):

A key part of scraping data from a webpage is to look at the HTML source of the webpage to properly get the data out. In the link you have provided, there are the following lines that contain the author information.

```
<meta name="author" content="Maggie Haberman, Michael D. Shear and Glenn Thrush" />
<meta name="byl" content="By MAGGIE HABERMAN, MICHAEL D. SHEAR and GLENN THRUSH" />
<meta property="article:author" content="https://www.nytimes.com/by/maggie-haberman" />
<meta property="article:author" content="https://www.nytimes.com/by/michael-d-shear" />
<meta property="article:author" content="https://www.nytimes.com/by/glenn-thrush" />
```

There are others but these should help. For parsing these tags you can use [beautiful-soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).